# No recibo un dato enviado desde un fetch a php

Tags: javascript, php, html5, mysqli, fetch

Estoy capturando un id de unos proyectos mediante el click, ya que los id vienen de un forEach. Almaceno ese id en una variable en javascript luego la envio por fetch a php mediante POST, pero cuando voy a mi archivo php y hago un var dump a la varible enviado por post me arroja un null y que ademas dicha varible no esta definida. Si llegaste hasta aqui muchísimas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de leer esto y de comentar la solución

HTML donde estoy imprimiendo el id mediante el forEach

```
<aside class="contenedor-proyectos">
    <div class="panel crear-proyecto">
        <a href="#" class="boton">Nuevo Proyecto <i class="fas fa-plus"></i> </a>
    </div>

    <div class="panel lista-proyectos">
        <h2>Proyectos</h2>
        <ul id="proyectos">
            <?php 
             $proyectos=obtenerProyectos();
             if ($proyectos) {
                 foreach ($proyectos as $proyecto) { ?>
                        <li class="lista-proyectos2">
                            <a href="index.php?id_proyecto=<?php echo $proyecto['id']?>" id='<?php echo $proyecto['id']?>' class='enlace'>
                                <?php echo $proyecto['nombre']?>
                            </a>
                            
                        </li>
                    
                     
            <?php      }
             }
            ?>   
        </ul>
    </div>
</aside>
```

Javascript donde capturo el id cuando doy click

```
var enlaces=document.getElementsByClassName('enlace');
for(let el of enlaces){
    el.addEventListener('click', obtener_id_proyecto);
}
    function obtener_id_proyecto(e){
 e.preventDefault();
console.log('presionaste en un proyecto');
var id_p=this.id;

//Enviando datos por Fetch
let datos=new FormData();
datos.append('id', id_p);
fetch('./inc/funciones/funciones.php',{
    method: 'POST',
    body: datos
})
    .then(function(response) {
       if(response.ok) {
           return response.text()
       } else {
           throw "Error en la llamada Ajax";
       }
      });

// alert(this.id);
console.log(datos);
}
```

PHP

```
function obtenerNombreProyecto(){
  $id_proyecto=$_POST['id'];

include 'conexion.php';
try{
    return mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT nombre FROM proyectos WHERE id = {$id_proyecto}");
} catch(Exception $e){
    echo "Error! : ". getMessage($e);
    return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He saneado/simplificado tu código, para hacerlo funcional, y tras probarlo, me **funciona correctamente**, salvo que tienes mal la recogida de datos en el `fetch`, deberías tenerlo así:

```
let datos=new FormData();
datos.append('id', id_p);
fetch('./inc/funciones/funciones.php',{
    method: 'POST',
    body: datos
})
    .then(function(response) {
       if(response.ok) {
           return response.text()
       } else {
           throw "Error en la llamada Ajax";
       }
      })
.then(function(datosRecibidos){console.log(datosRecibidos)});
```

Ten en cuenta que tu variable `datos` es la información que mandas, y la nueva variable `datosRecibidos` del segundo `.then` es donde se recoge la información del PHP.

Respecto al PHP, lo he sustituido por este más simple, pero el `$POST["id"]` llega perfectamente.

```
<?php
  $id_proyecto=$_POST['id'];
  echo "escribiend_desde_PHP: ".$id_proyecto
?>
```

He realizado las pruebas en un servidor web externo y online.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda. ¿Entonces lo que me faltaba era el segundo then?

Comment: No lo sé. Tu problema era que el id no llegaba al PHP, o si?

Comment: Exacto! . ¿Si probaste un var_dump a la variable id_proyecto?

Comment: No hizo falta. Me devolvió el id correcto, y eso es porque llegó primero.

Comment: En la consola no me arroja nada, es decir, la repuesta del PHP está en blanco

Comment: ¿Ruta al PHP? ¿Configuración del servidor web?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138676/discussion-between-kenlymar-paredes-and-enrique-garcia).